# reactjs MUI override style with parent reference

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

i want to override on specific component with parent reference, like search input text on datatable, right now i override the whole input to achive this

```
overrides:{ 
    mycomponentselector: { 
       MuiPaper: {
          MuiTabs: {
              PrivateTabIndicator: {
                  root: {
                     backgroundColor: 'red'
                  }
              }
          }
       }
   } 
}
```

[image: reference to override]

this is one of the example where i want to remove underline on the input search datatable but i end up override the whole input

[image]

i am sorry for my bad explanation,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can select the component only if it's inside a parent component (in this example the parent component is `Card`)

```
overrides: {
  MuiCard: {
    root: {
      "& .MuiInputBase-root:not(.Mui-disabled)": {
        "&::before, &::after": {
          borderBottom: "none !important"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit Material-UI TextField Underline Override]

Comment: my code above work good, but what i want is how to add parent selector on the override
ex : PhoneComp: { MuiInput: { underline : { so i can target the override and will only work on PhoneComp

Comment: @RickyOrlandoNapitupulu I've updated my answer and the live demo regarding your concern. Please have a look.